# OSMF Player stops working when deployed onto Apache Tomcat server

Tags: flash, video, osmf

I downloaded OSMF Sample player and opened osmf.html, (C:\player\osmf.html)it worked perfectly without any problem.

The same file when I deployed onto tomcat server,(http://localhost:8080/player/osmf.html) I get the error "The specified capability is not currently supported" while debugging.

I suspect of a flash security problem. Couldn't think of anything else.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using DeMonster Debugger to figure out what was going on. Actually I was using ReOps' OSMF player. That was the one working when I launched from Filesystem, not working when deployed on to tomcat server. The reason is that they have written to code to see if it is allowed to access a video from a particular domain. For file, it was returning true all the time. But for the domain localhost:8080, it was returning false.

After disabling that security check, it worked normally.

Thanks Andrian for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of content are you trying to play? Is the OSMF Sample player compiled for Flash Player 10.1? I suspect it's a version related issue.

Can you try using the Strobe Media Playback (https://sourceforge.net/adobe/smp) too? In the download section you can get binaries for both 10.0 and 10.1.

Strobe Media Playback is also built on top of OSMF, so it should help in troubleshooting your issue.

-Andrian